# Should a getter be allowed to return a different value than was passed to the setter?

Tags: c#, setters

For example, given the following class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    //...

    private IEnumerable<SomeType> myEnumerable;

    public IEnumerable<SomeType> MyEnumerable
    {
        get => myEnumerable;
        set => myEnumerable = value ?? new List<SomeType>();
    }
}
```

Is it good practice to perform this type of coercion in the setter (or in the getter), or is it more important not to have the property behave differently than a field - for example, in the following scenario:

```
var obj = new SomeClass();
IEnumerable<SomeType> enumerable = GetEnumerable(); //returns null
obj.MyEnumerable = enumerable;
Assert.AreEqual(enumerable, obj.MyEnumerable); //wrong!
```

Comment: The code with the problem is the function returning `null` and calling it an `IEnumerable<SomeType>`. It should probably return [Empty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Would getting a default value when nothing was set be an example?

Comment: It depends on what your API contract requires.  If your getter must always return an object that works with chained Linq operators, you can *never* return a null.  If your getter must always return what you set, then you cannot coerce it to another object.

Comment: For collectiona and arrays, (in Java at least) It would not be uncommon to see setters/getters doing copies or deep clones. The idea is to avoid consumers modifying the former  collection/array

Comment: If you want to avoid setting nulls, instead of assigning the input to the var, make your class to hold a collection, copy the elements of the enumerable (input) into the collection. Make the getter to return a iterable from the collection.

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody has suggested throwing an exception if you set with null.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

**You have a few combined questions here.**

- Is a setter allowed to store a different value than it received?

Yes, if it is warranted. However, for a *reference* type, you should really be storing the default value instead of merely returning it. Otherwise, it may create unexpected behavior.

- Is a getter allowed to return a different value than is stored?

Yes, if it is warranted.

- Is this current example a situation where you need to do this?

No. In this example, it's a bad workaround solution to a completely different problem.

---

**Why you shouldn't do it in this example.**

The issue with your code is that the solution is implemented in a different place than the problem, rendering your code disjointed.

```
public IEnumerable<SomeType> MyEnumerable
{
    get => myEnumerable;
    set => myEnumerable = value ?? new List<SomeType>();
}
```

The "custom" piece of logic here is `?? new List<SomeType>()`. Everything else is a default implementation of a property. This code is the logical equivalent of "we need to convert `null` values into a default value".

If we need to convert `null` values into a default value; the first question you should ask yourself is **where the `null` value is coming from**, which is here:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> enumerable = GetEnumerable(); //returns null
```

And now we see the disjointed problem/solution:

- The **problem** occurs inside the `GetEnumerable()` method.
- The **solution** occurs inside the property of a class which is used to store the `GetEnumerable()` return value.

This is problematic, for several reasons:

- If `GetEnumerable()` is used in other locations, and you're storing the value in `SomeOtherClass`, then this class needs to *also* handle potential `null` values. This violates the DRY principle.
- It also unnecessarily ties `SomeClass` to the `GetEnumerable()` method, since it contains validation that is (fairly) specific to the output of the `GetEnumerable()` method. This violates the separation of concerns.

---

**The best solutions, in order of preference.**

> 1. Change the `GetEnumerable()` method.

Ideally, a method should never return `null`. There are exceptions to this, but they are not the case for your example.
E.g. a method like `SingleOrDefault()` somewhat explicitly specifies that `null` is a *meaningful* return value. By using `SingleOrDefault()` instead of `Single()`, the developer has explicitly specified that he'd rather have a `null` (or defined default) value instead of an exception. The developer is therefore **aware** that he may encounter `null` values (unless he specified a different default value).

This is simply fixed in the `GetEnumerable()` method body. If the return statement is:

```
return myVariable;
```

it can simply be changed to:

```
return myVariable ?? new List<SomeType>();
```

Problem solved, no `null` values will be returned.

However, it's possible that you have no access to the method itself, e.g. if this is a method from an external library.

> 2. Immediately handle any returned `null`.

Simply put, you inline the method call and the null-handling:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> enumerable = GetEnumerable() ?? new List<SomeType>();
```

While the method can still return `null`, which you have no control over, you *immediately* convert that `null` into an empty list. All your subsequent code is no longer required to assess whether or not a `null` value might have been passed.

**Side comment**:
If this method is used in many different locations, it's worth it to wrap the method in another method which handles the `null` values:

```
public List<SomeType> GetEnumerableOrDefault()
{
     return GetEnumerable() ?? new List<SomeType>();
}
```

This way, you don't have to put `?? new List<SomeType>()` every time you want to call `GetEnumerable()`.

---

**Other cases where you would want to change the getter/setter value:**

This is just to give you a better use cases where you'd want to meddle with the values:

- Preventing illogical values, e.g. a negative age:

e.g.

```
public int Age
{
    get => _age;
    set => _ age = value < 0 ? 0 : value;
}
```

*Note: By modern day standards, this is considered putting business logic into a property; which is frowned upon. However, arguments can be made for **simple** applications to use such an approach.*

- Preventing null references in case the property has not been initialized:

e.g.

```
public string Name
{
    get => _name ?? "John Doe";
    set => _name = value;
}
```

*Note:*

- I'm struggling to find a *good* reason to use this. If it's a value type, null is generally not an issue. If it's a reference type, it's dangerous to not store the default object in the field. Strings could possibly be an exception to this, but for string, you'll often want to check for empty values as well. So I can't think of a *good* use case right now, other than nullable value types (which is not all that common).
- More often than not, the property should either already be initialized in the constructor or by initializing it. Generally, the issue lies with whoever decided to set a `null` value, as opposed to the unlucky caller who happens to receive a `null` value after the fact.
- For strings, a more sensible approach would be to check for empty strings as well: `get => String.IsNullOrWhitespace(_name) ? "John Doe" : _name;`.
- **Do not use this for reference types**. You'll end up causing unexpected behavior for an external caller, as you *pretend* that the value is inside the property, but behind the scenes you never stored it.

Comment: Your last example is a very bad idea.  You return the list but throw away the reference.  Big surprise for the user who puts something in it and then finds it vanish!  Instead: myEnumerable = myEnumerable ?? new List<SomeType>();  return myEnumerable;

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Fair point. I was probably distracted by the value type I used in the previous example :)

Answer (score 2):

To me, it would seem confusing for a developer to write

```
someObject.List = null;
someObject.Add(item);
```

It would make more sense for that sort of thing to throw an exception. The developer ought to write

```
someObject.List = new List<SomeType>();
someObject.List.Add(item);
```

Or better yet,

```
someObject.List.Clear();
someObject.List.Add(item);
```

So I guess a more standard way to implement your property would be like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private IEnumerable<SomeType> myEnumerable = new List<SomeType>();

    public IEnumerable<SomeType> MyEnumerable
    {
        get => myEnumerable;
        set => {
                   if (value == null) throw new ExceptionOfSomeKind();
                   myEnumerable = value;
               }
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    //This is readonly now-- can be set only when instantiated
    private readonly List<SomeType> myEnumerable = new List<SomeType>();

    public List<SomeType> MyList
    {
        get => myEnumerable;
        //Notice no setter!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: The last example here is probably the right thing. It’s unlikely OP actually needs a setter.

Comment: @RubberDuck I like the setter here for two reasons: a) it allows for deserialization into the object directly from eg. an ASP.NET WebAPI request parameter, and b) it lets the user initialize with an object initializer without having to treat collection properties specially.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Can initialize in ctor

Answer (score 1):

The entire reason to uses properties with getters and setters is exactly because you don't always want to return what's passed to it.

Otherwise why would you use anything else then a field?

Comment: To make a field externally readonly; but generally, good point +1

Comment: No set is not a valid reason?